# GCM don't register in some devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error while trying to register with GCM. 
My AVD target is Android 4.2.2 and API level is 17.
With SGS3 4.2.2 works fine, Galaxy GT-I9003 and with all version of Emulator don't work.
I've imported all libs, in right folders. If anyone can help we, please write the solution!

```
07-22 16:09:02.023: W/System.err(12698): java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
07-22 16:09:02.023: W/System.err(12698):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
07-22 16:09:02.023: W/System.err(12698):    at appgelato.ui.HomeActivity$5.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:237)
07-22 16:09:02.031: W/System.err(12698):    at appgelato.ui.HomeActivity$5.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
07-22 16:09:02.031: W/System.err(12698):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-22 16:09:02.039: W/System.err(12698):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-22 16:09:02.039: W/System.err(12698):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-22 16:09:02.039: W/System.err(12698):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-22 16:09:02.039: W/System.err(12698):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-22 16:09:02.039: W/System.err(12698):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

my code is:

```
try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    while (regid.equals("")) {
                        regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID); //STOP HERE AND CALL EXCEPTION
                        msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;
                        setRegistrationId(context, regid);
                    }
                    Controller.setDeviceToken(regid);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

                }
```

Comment: More then likely you have no internet connection for those devices. But show your code, we can't do anything more then suggest what could be wrong without code to overlook.

Comment: I'm sure I have connection, all two devices are connected at the same wifi.

Comment: Does each device have a registered google account? thats the only other thing that i know of that would cause a service unavailable error.

Comment: yes, GT-I9003 have one account of gmail, Virtual Devices No.

Comment: For gcm to work you need at least 1 registered google account available on the device

Comment: But, one question, google account isn't egual to gmail account?

Comment: they are equal, but you have to make sure you have it added on the device, goto Settings -> Accounts and make sure there is at least one google account in there

Comment: I'm sure there is!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your AVD must have Google API's Target.
And you must have configurated one google account